# Connecting Oracle custom jsp and standard from, Oracle R12

Tags: oracle, jsp, quotes

I have been working with Oracle ebusiness R12. In previous work on 11i I implemented a quote search .jsp that searches through specific tables and returns data in the form of a table. I was wondering if there was a way to create a Hyperlink that would link the jsp to the Standard Oracle search page and search for the same quote and display its contents? To reiterate I want the custom quote search to link to the standard quote search.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific to what you mean by "Standard Oracle search page"?

Comment: In the ebusiness suite i am using there is a standard search page that takes quote numbers as parameters and returns results. What I am hoping to accomplish is to create a hyperlink on my custom jsp that allows you to click on the quote number on the custom page and have it link to the Oracle standard search page. Would this be possible? Thanks for your time

Comment: It could be possible based on how complicated the SSO (Single Sign on) OID settings are on your environment. e-business will not be a URL based application so calling the Base search page from your custom jsp, authenticating, and then passing values might be tricky. We did something similar but in our case it was OBI Publisher instead of e-Business, which stands behind SSO authentication and with major help from Oracle themselves we were able to cook up our custom API that allows us to integrate BI Publisher with external applications which do not have visibility to SSO.